# python cgi (without flask) - can't get out of header error

Tags: python, apache2, cgi

Saw the advice from existing posts and did:

(1) Took care of "`SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal`" by putting

(2) Supposedly took care of bad header with "`print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"`"

But still.

```
[Tue Jul 12 14:55:59 2016] [error] [client 172.16.1.18] malformed header from script. Bad header=172.16.1.18 [has executed] d: reset.py, referer: http://172.16.1.18/cgi-bin/index.cgi?message=
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[part of index.cgi]

```
 <form name="input" action="/cgi-bin/reset.py" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Reset">
```

[reset.py]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting
import os
import subprocess
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
from subprocess import *
message = form.getvalue("message", "(no message)")
print os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]+ " [has executed] " + Popen('ls', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print """
<html>
<h2><title>Resetting</title>
<body>
<h3> Resetting </h3>
<p>Done</p>
</body>
</html"
print """
print cgi.escape(message)
```

Comment: What is that first print statement for, though?

Comment: i want "reset.py" to display who has executed this reset script.  'ls' will be replaced with a script as soon as I get this figured out.

Comment: But you're printing that as part of the headers. Couldn't that be part of your problem?

Comment: moved it down and it works. Thank you (Still learning through python-cgi/html)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to "Daniel Roseman" 
Moved a command below header. 
I thought backbone codes that aren't directly html don't belong below.

```
import subprocess
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
from subprocess import *
message = form.getvalue("message", "(no message)")
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]+ " [has executed] " + Popen('df -h', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
print """
```